# How to use AngularJS to lazy load content in a collapsible panel

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, lazy-loading

I am building an application that uses the [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) component to render a sequence of panels, all of which will initially be in the collapsed state.

Since the page may contain many such panels and each of them may contain a large amount of content, it seems appropriate to populate these panels on demand, by executing an AJAX call when the user expands any panel.

The dynamic content of the page (including the markup for the panels) is rendered using AngularJS, and I assume it's possible to configure Angular to bind to an event on the panel elements, that results in their content being lazy loaded when they expand.

Unfortunately, after looking at the AngularJS docs and the available tutorials, I can't see how best to tackle this. Can anyone throw any light on it?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Comment: Simply use `<div ng-include="panelTemplate"></div>` inside your panels and define/set `panelTemplate` var at the moment you open the panel. This will execute the XHR request and fetch the panel view only at the moment the panel is opened for the first time.

Comment: Thanks Stewie. This looks like a promising approach, but I am not clear how to trigger the define/set of panelTemplate when the panel is opened. If you wish to post an answer with a code example, I will try it and (probably) accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tim Coulter, I've created something following the idea of @Stewie.

It can definitely be improved, but I guess it's a good starting point.

I've created a small directive to bind the click event of the accordion's panel. When the click event is fired, I passed the panel template via the `panel-template=` attribute and it updates the `main-template` which is used inside the panel.

It makes reference to 2 html files (panel1.html and panel2.html) that contains the content of the each panel.
I would recommend to create a service to fetch these files via AJAX - just the way you wanted.
On the code below I created a service called `dataService` for this purpose and you should bind it to the `click` event - so files are loaded on demand when the user clicks on it.

Note the the mainTemplate is a common panel to all accordions, so when it changes the all the accordions will have the same content, BUT I am assuming you want to display **only one panel at time**, right ?!

Anyway as I said before the logic can be improved to fix these little 'gotchas', but I believe the core functionality is there to start with. :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


    myApp.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {
        $scope.oneAtATime = true;

        $scope.mainTemplate = '';

        $scope.groups = [
          {
            id: "001",
            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
            content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1",
            template: "panel1.html"
          },
          {
            id: "002",
            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
            content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2",
            template: "panel2.html"

          }
        ];

    }]);

    myApp.factory('dataService', [ '$http', function($http){
      return {
          getData: function() {
            return // you AJAX content data here;
          }
      }
    }]);

    myApp.directive('accordionToggle', [function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
         scope: {
         mainTemplate: '=',
         panelTemplate: '@'
       },
       link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {

         element.bind('click', function(e){

           scope.mainTemplate = scope.panelTemplate;

           scope.$apply();

         });
       }
     };
   }]);


    </script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

  <div class="accordion" id="accordionParent">
    <div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="group in groups" >
     <div class="accordion-heading">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" main-template="$parent.mainTemplate" panel-template="{{ group.template }}" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionParent" href="#collapse{{ $parent.group.id }}">
         Collapsible Group Item {{ $parent.group.id }}
       </a>
     </div>
     <div id="collapse{{ group.id }}" class="accordion-body collapse">
       <div class="accordion-inner">
         <div class="include-example" ng-include="mainTemplate"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That's a great solution. Thanks for taking the time to create it for me.

Comment: This is a good solution and even works for foundation accordion. Thanks for the sharing this. For those people who are interested in the solution for angular-foundation I'm sharing this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KkZlqs3UDdYE0805DTm9?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

This is way old, but the question might still come up now and then. I now find this to be the most suitable solution without polluting your controllers:
(`myDirective` loading its content via AJAX right after its creation.)

```
<accordion>
  <accordion-group 
    heading=""
    ng-repeat="foo in bar"
    ng-init="status = {load: false}"
    ng-click="status.load = true">

  <myDirective ng-if="status.load"></myDirective>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

each element created by `ng-repeat` gets its own $scope, so clicking ab accordion-group will result in only the respective directive being loaded.

edit:
depending on latency and the size of the data that's to be lazy loaded, you might consider using `ng-mouseover` instead of `ng-click`. That way loading starts some 100ms before the user opens the accordion which can reduce 'sluggishness' of your UI. Obviously there's the downside of occasionally loading content of groups that are never actually clicked.